# What does Careers have against October?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

SO Careers does not allow the month of October to be spelled out in any date field (`Oct` works fine)

How could that possibly happen?

Comment: October knows what it did wrong!

Comment: ... Something about a revolution in October, once?

Comment: Jeff hates Sean Connery.  Go ahead, try putting the word "Red" in there - *it doesn't work either!*

Comment: I'm sure the explanation will not be nearly as interesting as any cause I can imagine...or will it?!...no it won't :/

Comment: Oh, and did you notice October is the 10th month on the calendar, but according to its name "Oct," it should be the 8th!? If only Chacha102 could reveal more to us regarding this massive-coverup!

Comment: Why do programmers always get Halloween and Christmas confused? Because oct(31) == dec(25).

Comment: @Jonathan: blame the Romans, it's all their fault.  October was named back before "January" and "February" were prepended to the year, so it *was* the 8th month.  as Sept. was the 7th, Nov. the 9th, and Dec. the 10th.  sadly no one remembers those old pre-Julian calendars: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_calendar http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/September

Comment: Talk about an [Eternal September](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Time Frames are... complex.  This is (yet another) error resulting from tightening the data entry constraints on Time Frames .

Suffice to say that there (was) a point in the time frame parsing code where we split it into two different strings that can be converted directly into DateTimes.

This was accomplished with something roughly equivalents to:

```
Regex.Split(timeFrame, @"to|-");
```

The exact explanation of the error is left as an exercise to the reader.

<sub>We of course haven't written our own date parsing code, as down that path lies wailing and much gnashing of teeth.</sub>

Comment: LOL!  That's pretty good.  Thanks for checking into this!

Comment: **Note to self:** add all full and partial months to date parsing unit test.

Comment: Why is it necessary to "tighten the data entry constraints"?

Comment: @Kyle - probably to make it easier to calculate length of employment.

Comment: It works now...

Comment: @Pollyanna But why is that necessary to do? Surely employers could determine that by reading the CV, and it seems like an odd thing to search by.

Comment: @Kyle Cronin - hResume is very stringent about date formatting, so in order to better support hResume export Time Frame data needed to be more readily parse-able.  We still try and let you get away with a bunch of different formats, if only for convenience sake.

Comment: The time frame cannot hold, it is too late...

Comment: @kyle - I'm only guessing, I couldn't think of a good reason why an employer would need to search or know that detail either, but... @Kevin - Ah!  That makes very good sense!

Comment: @Andrew - cthresume would like to have a word with you.

Answer (score 8):

Confirmed:

[image]

I don't get a similar error with `Oct 2005-2007`

I'm thinking someone misspelled October in the date checking code.  I should win a Pony if I'm right.

Also, the Red October conspiracy (as noted in the question comments) seems to be more likely given the color of the error box, and the month that causes the error.

Crazy Ivan indeed.

Comment: My bets are on Octber.

Comment: *fest*.  everyone forgets the *fest* in *Octoberfest*.  it's not a month, it's a beer-drinking excuse!

Comment: @snicker - nope.  I've tried that and a few other spelling variations and they all have the same rejected result.  I'm really curious as to what it is now...